# Creating a mask to override nn.Linear

Tags: pytorch

I would like to override nn.linear using a mask like so

```
class MaskedLinear(nn.Linear):
    def __init__(self, *args, mask, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mask = mask

    def forward(self, input):
        return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)*self.mask
```

My problem is coming up with a suitable mask.
I have 11 X 10 making 110 neuron layer that is split into 11's like a music group or the group D12. D12 has generators  5 and 7 . i would like to make connections in the order that they are generated by each generator, i.e. the cycle of fourths and fifths.
How would i create a mask for this?
I have a recurrent layer that will take this mask and make the connections.